# SharePoint site user get Forbidden error while access SharePoint site

Tags: site, access, 403

**Forbidden error 403** : site is opened but this user does not have permission to access this site

This error surprised me because If user does not have permission to access SharePoint site then error might be **"sorry,you do not have permission for this site"**, but this time **"forbidden"** error shown

Tried solution:

Default browser : IE
Reset IE
Prompt open every time user login in IE

Answer (score 1):

1)Share point server takes user from Active directory.
So check the user permission in Active Directory of the windows server.
If user is not in active directory than share point is not allowing user to enter in site.I can say there some thing fussy between Active directory and share point web application authentication local server group.

2) Check Local server group in IIS.

Refrence:

> http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/04/30/intermittent-quot-http-403-forbidden-quot-error-while-trying-to-browse-to-a-sharepoint-web-app.aspx

Note:  If you have set up for **anonymous access** in share point site than server not going to take user in AD.

Enable anonymous access :

> https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Enable-anonymous-access-3647cdd5-1ab8-48cf-b4ee-d1b652bbabdd

Answer (score 0):

It simple thing which I out of mind.

server not able to check permission for user because Application pool account and Managed account in Central admin As not per Best practice

That's why SharePoint can't able processed in permission check so every time get Forbidden error

After Configure my IIS pool account As per Best Practice It will be fine

Reference Link : [Link](http://nikpatel.net/2012/01/25/best-practices-to-change-app-pool-account-for-sharepoint-web-applcation/)